AttributeError: 'OpenAI' object has no attribute 'fine_tunes'
I work with Python in Jupyter Notebook 7.0.8 :
Here is the error generated by the following cell:
The error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 5
      2 dataset_path = r"*****"
      4 # Fine-tune the model with the examples from the dataset
----> 5 fine_tuned_model_id = fine_tune_model_with_examples(dataset_path)
      6 print(f"Fine-tuned model ID: {fine_tuned_model_id}")
      8 # Example source code to analyze

Cell In[9], line 34, in fine_tune_model_with_examples(dataset_path)
     26 # Launch fine-tuning
     27 fine_tuning_parameters = {
     28     "training_file": train_file_id,
     29     "validation_file": test_file_id,
     30     "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
     31     "n_epochs": 4
     32 }
---> 34 response = client.fine_tunes.create(**fine_tuning_parameters)
     35 return response['id']

AttributeError: 'OpenAI' object has no attribute 'fine_tunes'

The cell causing the error:
# Function to fine-tune the model
def fine_tune_model_with_examples(dataset_path):
    # Load and balance the dataset
    balanced_dataset = load_and_balance_dataset(dataset_path)

    # Split the dataset into training and test sets
    train_set, test_set = split_dataset(balanced_dataset)

    # Prepare fine-tuning data in chat format
    train_examples = prepare_fine_tuning_data(train_set)
    test_examples = prepare_fine_tuning_data(test_set)

    # Save training and test data to JSONL files
    save_to_jsonl(train_examples, "train_fine_tuning_data.jsonl")
    save_to_jsonl(test_examples, "test_fine_tuning_data.jsonl")

    # Upload training and test data to OpenAI
    with open("train_fine_tuning_data.jsonl", 'rb') as train_file:
        train_file_response = client.files.create(file=train_file, purpose='fine-tune')
    with open("test_fine_tuning_data.jsonl", 'rb') as test_file:
        test_file_response = client.files.create(file=test_file, purpose='fine-tune')

    train_file_id = train_file_response.id
    test_file_id = test_file_response.id

    # Launch fine-tuning
    fine_tuning_parameters = {
        "training_file": train_file_id,
        "validation_file": test_file_id,
        "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        "n_epochs": 4
    }

    response = client.fine_tunes.create(**fine_tuning_parameters)
    return response['id']

I made sure to update all the packages used.
However, it is indicated (https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742) among the changes made with the update of the OpenAI API that: openai.FineTune.create() is now client.fine_tunes.create().
Does anyone have a solution to suggest to me?
Thank you in advance ;)

Please cite & link the place you see things. I think I finally found what you are referencing here: "openai.File.create() -> client.files.create()". What you have supplied though continues to only give us insight into a portion of the the possible issue. At the link, I reference it talks about initiating client earlier. I would speculate that part isn't correct. However, not having the code supplied in the post, it makes it just that: pure speculation. Please read ...

 How do I ask a good question?, paying special attention to the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' where it talks about a minimal, reproducible example. And then update your post. Also please update your post to demonstrate what version of the openai package you have. There is a possibility that what you think you are using, isn't what you are using as Jupyter manages the environment where the kernel is running a little differently than people often assume. Minor thing: "I work with Jupyter Notebook". You work with a Python ...

 kernel running in a Jupyter Notebook. This is clear in this case; however, realizing this and being clear in your thinking and details will help going forward for you troubleshooting your own issues and helping those trying to help you. Jupyter Notebooks can use a lot of language kernels. Historically it developed from the IPython Notebook project, but now can run many languages, and so it is always best to specify. A lot of the issue you may encounter will be independent of the development environment & so focusing on Jupyter & thinking it is equivalent with Python may be unwise.

Initiating client is correct :)
# OpenAI API key
api_key = "***"
client = openai.OpenAI(api_key=api_key)


Okay. What does %pip list run in the running Jupyter notebook say the version is?

I was able to solve the issue by replacing the portion of code that was no longer compatible with API V1:
# Upload training and test data to OpenAI
with open("*****.jsonl", 'rb') as train_file:
    train_file_response = client.files.create(file=train_file, purpose='fine-tune')

Thank you for the help.
